# Fix Random numbers

Tags: r

When the run the below code, the random numbers are different everytime I run this. Is there a way to fix this? I mean the random number should be same all time

```
sample(1:10)
```

Comment: True random numbers won't be repeatable. If you want repeatable pseudorandom numbers, use a generator that doesn't have any other source of randomness except the seed, and use the same seed every time.

Comment: https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.11/repeatable.html

Answer (score 1):

Use `set.seed` method

```
    set.seed(666)
    sample(1:10)
```